# Select Query Works fine in Access2010 but not in C# code

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a simple Select Query which works fine in Access but not in C# code
Here is the query

```
SELECT FIRST(ItemName) As Item 
from SubmitData  
where ItemName like 'txt_rdo_breaks*' 
and Deleted=false
```

Here is its result in Access
[image]

But in C# code it retruns nothing
Here is C# code

```
 cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT FIRST(ItemName) As Item from SubmitData  where ItemName like 'txt_" + controlPatrs[0] + "*' and Deleted=false";
 OleDbDataReader reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default);
 while (reader1.Read())
 {
     if (Convert.ToString(reader1["Item"]).Length > 1)
     {
          tag += Convert.ToString(reader1["Item"]) + "|txt_" + controlPatrs[0] + "|" + controlPatrs[2] + "||";
     }

  }
 reader1.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: Change `Deleted=false` to `Deleted=0`.

Comment: FIRST is unique to MS Access.  Do you get a result if you change it to MAX or some other function?

Comment: @MairajAhmad: still same

Comment: @MairajAhmad if putting ``false`` is working in access, it should work from c# code as well

Comment: try sepcifying commandType to text

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: already done..!

Comment: can you inspect the ``cmd1.CommandText`` in quick watch what is inside it after the query is assigned?

Comment: see what other values you can put in CommandBehaviour

Comment: can you post the whole code (including connection string)? Does you code enters while loop at all?

Comment: `OleDbProvider` query seems to require a different wildcard characters - '%' and '_`

Comment: @Viru: yes it does return 1 row but there is no data in it.

Comment: I think OLEdb supports % instead of * as pointed out by @IvanStoev. Try after replcing * with %

Comment: yup it worked, in access it works with * but in C# code % works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following **Ivan Stoev's** comment

```
OleDbProvider query seems to require a different wildcard characters - '%'
```

in Access it worked with `*` sign but while using OleDbProvider `%` sign worked.
so the correct command text is

```
cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT FIRST(ItemName) As Item from SubmitData  where ItemName like 'txt_" + controlPatrs[0] + "%' and Deleted=false";
```